# android java pick color from ImageView

Tags: java, android

I'm using the latest Android IDE. I have an eyedropper icon in my UI that lets the user select a color from a bitmap that the app has thrown up. I have a listener set up on the icon, but I can't find a way to make it wait for the next touch, from which it could work out the pixel color. It's simple code so far:

```
//Open the eyedropper
    dropBtn = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.drop_btn);
    dropBtn.setOnTouchListener( new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), colPickMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();

                float x = event.getX();
                float y = event.getY();

                switch (event.getAction()) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                        p1.x = (int) x;
                        p1.y = (int) y;

                        final int sourceColor = drawView.drawableBitmap.getPixel((int) x, (int) y);
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

The problem is the code just blast through, and the pixel it reports on is one in the icon that selects the eyedropper. I need the code to wait for the next click and report on that. All suggestions will be valued.

Here's the code for the drawing view.

```
package com.softwareandgeneral.drawtutorial01;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawingView extends View {

    //drawing path
    private Path drawPath;
    //drawing and canvas paint
    private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
    //initial color
    private int paintColor = 0xFF660000;
    //canvas
    private Canvas drawCanvas;
    //canvas bitmap
    public Bitmap canvasBitmap, drawableBitmap;
    //brush sizes
    private float brushSize, lastBrushSize;
    //erase flag
    private boolean erase = false, paint_mode = false;

    final Point p1 = new Point();
    private Path path;

    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setupDrawing();
    }

    //setup drawing
    private void setupDrawing() {

        //prepare for drawing and setup paint stroke properties
        brushSize = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.medium_size);
        lastBrushSize = brushSize;
        drawPath = new Path();
        drawPaint = new Paint();
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
        drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
        drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    }

    //size assigned to view
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        canvasBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.doodle_01);
        drawableBitmap = canvasBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
        drawCanvas = new Canvas(drawableBitmap);
    }

    //draw the view - will be called after touch event
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(drawableBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
    }

    //update color
    public void setColor(String newColor) {
        invalidate();
        paintColor = Color.parseColor(newColor);
        drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    }

    //set brush size
    public void setBrushSize(float newSize) {
        float pixelAmount = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
                newSize, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        brushSize = pixelAmount;
        drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
    }

    //get and set last brush size
    public void setLastBrushSize(float lastSize) {
        lastBrushSize = lastSize;
    }

    public float getLastBrushSize() {
        return lastBrushSize;
    }

    //set erase true or false
    public void setErase(boolean isErase) {
        erase = isErase;
        if (erase) drawPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
        else drawPaint.setXfermode(null);
    }

    //start new drawing
    public void startNew() {
        drawCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
        invalidate();
    }

    // JRL:  function to return current paint color
    public int getPaintColor() {
        return drawPaint.getColor();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (paint_mode) {
            float touchX = event.getX();
            float touchY = event.getY();
            //respond to down, move and up events
            switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
                    drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
                    drawPath.reset();
                    break;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
            //redraw
            invalidate();
            return true;

        } else {

            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    p1.x = (int) x;
                    p1.y = (int) y;
                    final int sourceColor = drawableBitmap.getPixel((int) x, (int) y);
                    final int targetColor = drawPaint.getColor();
                    new TheTask(drawableBitmap, p1, sourceColor, targetColor).execute();
                    invalidate();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

This is getting closer. I've implemented the onTouch listener in MainActivity.onClick(View view) as per this code fragment:

```
else if (view.getId() == R.id.drop_btn) {
        //JRL:  color picker button clicked
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), colPickMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();

        drawView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    float x = event.getX();
                    float y = event.getY();

                    switch (event.getAction()) {
                        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                            p1.x = (int) x;
                            p1.y = (int) y;
                            final int sourceColor = drawView.drawableBitmap.getPixel((int) x, (int) y);
                            currPaint.setBackgroundColor(sourceColor);
                            String hexColor = String.format("#FF%06X", (0xFFFFFF & sourceColor));
                            currPaint.setTag(hexColor);
                            drawView.setColor(hexColor);
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

and this works. I can pick a color and the changes to the UI work fine. What doesn't work is that I'm stuck in this listener - the original onTouchEventlistener that I want to get back to. I haven't found a way to stop a listener in Android.

Comment: Does dropButton hold the image with the colors?

Comment: No. The image is in a separate view. I could change that if you would explain what you mean.

Comment: please post the code for the separate view

Comment: I added the drawing view as an edit to the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have it backwards. The problem is that  `OnTouchListener` means "when something touches me, do this" not "when I touch something, do this."

The listener looks good, but take this code and put it in the `OnTouchListener` for the colors bitmap, not the eyedropper icon.

Try this:

```
drawView.setOnTouchListener( new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), colPickMsg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

            float x = event.getX();
            float y = event.getY();

            switch (event.getAction()) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                    p1.x = (int) x;
                    p1.y = (int) y;

                    final int sourceColor = drawView.drawableBitmap.getPixel((int) x, (int) y);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is a good thought. I need to let it ferment for a while.

Comment: maybe the above code will work for you, because it seems that `drawView` is the View that holds the bitmap.

Comment: I'm getting closer. I've implemented the onTouch lister like this in MainActivity.onClick(View view) {}  `code`

Comment: I've put my latest code attempt up as an edit to my original posting. I haven't found a way to get code into a comment yet. I'm closer but still not working. I think I've misunderstood what you mean by "put it in the OnTouchListener for the colors bitmap"

Comment: So what's happening now? How is it misbehaving?

Comment: I have a picture on the canvas made up of white patches enclosed by black lines. The main function of the app is to area fill these patches with colors. This is done through a listener on the DrawingView object and implemented using an onClick function that is fired up by the listener. This problem relates to using an eyedropper to recover a color already used on the canvas, and I've implemented it by creating a new listener on the DrawingView object that fires up an onTouch function. I now have two listeners on that object.

Comment: While the new onTouch listener works, I can't get back to the onClick functionality of the first listener.

Comment: So one on touch listener is attached to the canvas, and the other is where?

Comment: The canvas object won't let me attach a listener - only the DrawingView object.

Comment: That sounds good as long as the DrawingView only holds the canvas. Each view should have its own onClick listener with commands that will occur when they are clicked. You should post more code.